# How to Rotate a Quad

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glfw, glm-math

I'm trying to make a quad rotate around its center. I am using `glm::rotate()` and setting the quad to rotate on the z axis. However when I do this it gives this weird effect. The quad stretches and warps. It almost looks 3d but since I am rotating it around the z axis that shouldn't happen right?

Here's relevant code for context:

```
    float rotation = 0.0f;
    double prevTime = glfwGetTime();

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) 
    {
        GLCall(glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

        GLCall(glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT));

        updateInput(window);

        shader.Use();
        glUniform1f(xMov, x);
        glUniform1f(yMov, y);
        test.Bind();

        double crntTime = glfwGetTime();
        if (crntTime - prevTime >= 1 / 60) 
        {
            rotation += 0.5f;
            prevTime = crntTime;
        }

        glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);

        model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(rotation), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

        int modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader.id, "model");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));

        vao.Bind();
        vBuffer1.Bind();
        iBuffer1.Bind();

        GLCall(glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0));

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        glfwPollEvents();
    }
```

Shader:

```
#version 440 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 aColor;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 aTex;

out vec3 color;
out vec2 texCoord;

uniform float xMove;
uniform float yMove;
uniform mat4 model;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = model * vec4(aPos.x + xMove, aPos.y + yMove, aPos.z, 1.0);
    color = aColor;
    texCoord = aTex;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you try rotating around the other 2 axis?

Comment: It looks exactly how you'd expect a 2d plane to look rotating in a 3d space. What I don't get is why it looks fine on the x and y axis but doesn't work for the z axis.

Comment: Which OpenGL version/profile are you targeting? Please add the shader to your question. What is `test.Bind();`?

Comment: I'm targeting gl4, `test.Bind();` is the texture file.

Comment: IIRC glm::rotate performs axis-angle rotation, not euler angle rotation. If there's anything I've learned from the early stages of graphics programming, it's that you can never trust that you understand what is actually going on, and that also pertains to what each axis actually represents.

Comment: [glm](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/glm/info) != [glm-math](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/glm-math/info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without you showing the graphical output it is hard to say.

Your first issue is, you are not rotating around the center, to rotate by the center you must, offset the quad so that its center is at 0,0. then rotate, then offset back to the original position, but you have this line:

`gl_Position = model * vec4(aPos.x + xMove, aPos.y + yMove, aPos.z, 1.0);`

Under the assumption that the quad as at the origin to begin with you are rotating it around the point (-xMove, -yMove).

Comment: I think it had to do with my window's resolution. Originally I had it set to match the resolution of my monitor. But I just tried setting it to be square shaped and now it's working. How can I account for resolutions that aren't square shaped?

Comment: You need a view transformation to cancel the shearing introduced by the OGL window. 

Ogl maps teh (-1, -1)-(1,1) square to your window, idf the window is not a square then you are mapping a square to a rectangel, which is obviously deformed.

I recommend you look into actual orthographic cameras but for now you can just multiply by the aspect ratio (either width/height or height/width, can;t remember which atm)

Comment: I can draw the square to the screen using the aspect ratio. However when I try to apply the rotation transformation it becomes all warped. How can I cancel out that effect?

Comment: You apply the deformation canceling AFTER rotating, it should be the very last step.

Comment: Maybe also like the answer then :)

Comment: I thought I did, I clicked the the green checkmark to the left of the question.

Comment: You did, I am mentioning you can also press the up arrow which gives an additional 10 points, but up to you.